# Query DB then use result to make more queries

Tags: php, database

Please take your time to read the full text. I know it is a lot but I can't describe it any shorter.

With the code below I can get the user group ID that is assigned to the logged in user in Joomla 3.

```
$user_  = JFactory::getUser();
$db     = JFactory::getDBO();
foreach($user_->groups as $group){
    $query  = 'SELECT id FROM #__usergroups';
    $query .= ' WHERE id = ' . $group;
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    echo $db->loadResult() . "<br>";
}
```

Most users are part of multiple groups and the above code also returns a list of all the user group ID's that the user is connected to.

**The Reason**

I need to make a list of all projects that are assigned to the current logged in user.

**The Way to Get That**

1. I need to get the User Group ID. (achieved with above code lets use as example the `ID 20`)
2. Then use this User Group ID(UGID) to search for a View Access ID(VAID) in the `view access table` where column "Rules" contains the UGID
3. Then search in the `project table` where the column "access" matches this VAID.
4. Return a list of all project titles.

**Why Ask Here**

I am not used to working with databases and quite out of my league here. I am getting stuck in step 2 as the code I have can return one ID or multiples. 
When it returns multiple ID's then I need to check each ID to the `view access table`

***Table Setups***

**User Groups Table**

Here is how this table is build (default Joomla 3 table. Cannot change this!):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#_usergroups` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Adjacency List Reference Id',
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set lft.',
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.',
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `y39kd_usergroups` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `title`) VALUES
(17, 14, 24, 25, 'Velthoven'),
(20, 14, 6, 7, 'Bouwman');
```

**View Access Table**

Here is how this table is build (default Joomla 3 table. Cannot change this!):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#_viewlevels` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rules` varchar(5120) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON encoded access control.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

A little bit of dummy content (here you can see that the Rules contains multiple ID's)

INSERT INTO `y39kd_viewlevels` (`id`, `title`, `ordering`, `rules`) VALUES
(13, 'Velthoven', 0, '[17,15,7,8]'),
(18, 'Bouwman', 0, '[20,15,7,8]');
```

**Project Table**

Here is how this table is build (default Joomla 3 projectfork table. Cannot change this!):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#_pf_projects` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Project ID',
  `asset_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'FK to the #__assets table',
  `catid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Category ID',
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Project title',
  `alias` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Title alias. Used in SEF URL''s',
  `description` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Project description',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Project creation date',
  `created_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Project owner',
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Project modify date',
  `modified_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Last user to modify the project',
  `checked_out` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User who is currently editing the project',
  `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Check-out date and time',
  `attribs` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Project attributes in JSON format',
  `access` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Project ACL access level ID',
  `state` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Project state: 1 = Active, 0 = Inactive, 2 = Archived, -2 = Trashed',
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Project start date',
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Project end date'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores Projectfork project data';

INSERT INTO `#_pf_projects` (`id`, `asset_id`, `catid`, `title`, `alias`, `description`, `created`, `created_by`, `modified`, `modified_by`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `attribs`, `access`, `state`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES
(26, 1274, 42, 'http://www.ls.velthovenbv.nl', 'http-www-ls-velthovenbv-nl', '', '2017-10-04 14:10:32', 439, '2017-10-04 14:11:30', 439, 994, '2017-10-18 13:32:22', '{"website":false,"email":"","phone":"","repo_dir":72,"project_color":"","milestone_color":"","tasklist_color":"","task_color":"","currency_code":"","currency_sign":"","currency_position":"","decimal_delimiter":"","thousands_delimiter":""}', 13, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(55, 4712, 57, 'http://www.ls.bouwmanbv.nl', 'http-www-ls-bouwmanbv-nl', '<p>List with Basic Milestones and Tasks to use for all Commercial Projects</p>', '2017-10-19 16:10:57', 994, '2017-10-19 16:12:48', 439, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '{"website":false,"email":"","phone":"","repo_dir":102,"project_color":"","milestone_color":"","tasklist_color":"","task_color":"","currency_code":"","currency_sign":"","currency_position":"","decimal_delimiter":"","thousands_delimiter":""}', 18, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(155, 4712, 57, 'http://www.ls.serious.nl', 'http-www-ls-serious-nl', '<p>List with Basic Milestones and Tasks to use for all Commercial Projects</p>', '2017-10-19 16:10:57', 994, '2017-10-19 16:12:48', 439, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '{"website":false,"email":"","phone":"","repo_dir":102,"project_color":"","milestone_color":"","tasklist_color":"","task_color":"","currency_code":"","currency_sign":"","currency_position":"","decimal_delimiter":"","thousands_delimiter":""}', 18, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(255, 4712, 57, 'http://www.ls.another.nl', 'http-www-ls-another-nl', '<p>List with Basic Milestones and Tasks to use for all Commercial Projects</p>', '2017-10-19 16:10:57', 994, '2017-10-19 16:12:48', 439, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '{"website":false,"email":"","phone":"","repo_dir":102,"project_color":"","milestone_color":"","tasklist_color":"","task_color":"","currency_code":"","currency_sign":"","currency_position":"","decimal_delimiter":"","thousands_delimiter":""}', 18, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(355, 4712, 57, 'http://www.ls.something.nl', 'http-www-ls-something-nl', '<p>List with Basic Milestones and Tasks to use for all Commercial Projects</p>', '2017-10-19 16:10:57', 994, '2017-10-19 16:12:48', 439, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '{"website":false,"email":"","phone":"","repo_dir":102,"project_color":"","milestone_color":"","tasklist_color":"","task_color":"","currency_code":"","currency_sign":"","currency_position":"","decimal_delimiter":"","thousands_delimiter":""}', 18, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

***Expected results from Code***

I expect to get the following results from the code that is described under chapter The Way to Get That:

1. User Group ID 20
2. View Access ID 18
3. Project IDs 55, 155, 255, 355 => Get Titles
4. http://www.ls.bouwmanbv.nl, http://www.ls.serious.nl, http://www.ls.another.nl, http://www.ls.something.nl

And when another user is logged in it shows for instance:

1. User Group ID 17
2. View Access ID 13
3. Project IDs 26 => Get Title
4. http://www.ls.velthovenbv.nl

***My tries so far***

In here I am posting information about the things I tried and this will make the pro's laugh out loud seeing me doing stupid stuff.

```
foreach($user_->groups as $group){
    $query  = 'SELECT id FROM #__usergroups';
    $query .= ' WHERE id = ' . $group;
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $ViewAccessquery  = 'SELECT id FROM #__viewlevels';
    $ViewAccessquery .= ' WHERE rules = ' . $group;
    $db->setQuery( $ViewAccessquery );
    echo $db->loadResult() . "<br>";
}
```

With the answer provided below from cmorrissey I am getting a bit closer. So far it is not yet working because there is a issue with below code.

```
  foreach($user_->groups as $group){
    $group_query  = 'SELECT id FROM #__usergroups';
    $group_query .= ' WHERE id = ' . $group;
    $db->setQuery( $group_query );
    echo $db->loadResult($group_query);
  }
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query->select('#__pf_projects'.'title');
  $query->from('#__pf_projects');
  $query->join('inner', $db->quoteName('#__viewlevels') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('#__viewlevels'.'id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('#__pf_projects'.'access') . ')');
  $query->join('inner', $db->quoteName('#__usergroups') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('#__usergroups'.'title') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('#__viewlevels'.'title') . ') AND FIND_IN_SET("#__usergroups"."id", :group_ids)');
  //$query->where('pdt'.'product_id' = 68);
  $db->setQuery($query);
  echo $db->loadResult($query);
```

The problem is within this part:

`AND FIND_IN_SET("#__usergroups"."id", :group_ids)');`

I tried to move it about but getting syntax errors in the editor. And when the code is as is I receive this error:

`1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '."id", :group_ids)' at line 4`

I know group_ids is not defined but I don't know if I can just change it into `group_query`?

***PS***
All data is fake data! All entities in above text are entirely fictional and not related to existing entities under the same name.

Comment: @ManuelOtto Sorry no, The field `Rules` contains the User Group ID's, So we check on this UGID to get the VAID and use this VAID to get the Project ID. It is cumbersome I am sorry about that but I can also not do anything about that. Yeah press delete ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly Joomla got some really nice features that can get this result way easier. I needed another SO question to achieve the result though.

[Removing empty spaces and BR from string in echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46936908/removing-empty-spaces-and-br-from-string-in-echo)

But I will also put the final code in here.

```
$user_  = JFactory::getUser();
$db     = JFactory::getDBO();
$levels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($user->id);
foreach($levels as $key => $level)
{
  $query  = 'SELECT title FROM #__pf_projects';
  $query .= ' WHERE access = ' . $level;
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $projectlist = '<div class="project">'.$db->loadResult($query).'</div>';
  echo $projectlist;
}
```

Creates a list like:

```
http://www.domain1.com
http://www.domain5.com
http://www.domain23.com
http://www.domain65.com
http://www.domain213.com
```

Which in our case are project titles.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
SELECT `#_pf_projects`.`title`
    FROM `#_pf_projects`
        INNER JOIN `#_viewlevels` ON `#_viewlevels`.`id` = `#_pf_projects`.`access`
        INNER JOIN `#_usergroups` ON `#_usergroups`.`title` = `#_viewlevels`.`title` AND FIND_IN_SET(`#_usergroups`.`id`, :group_ids)
    WHERE 1
```

And your :group_ids would be a comma separated list ie '20,18' or just '20' that way you don't need that other loop ... or you could go a step further and join some more and just use the user id to extract everything.

Comment: I wrote the question as last thing of the day and I am now at home. Did not expect a answer this quick. I have no access to the code now to test it out but do have tomorrow will check it then immediately. Thank you very much for providing code. I don't understand everything yet but I am sure that I will after a couple of Google searches.

I do have one question that baffles me a bit what does this say `WHERE 1`

If I can't figure it out can I please ask you more questions tomorrow?

Comment: You can leave `WHERE 1` off if you want its just a placeholder where you could add something like `WHERE \`alias\` = 'something'` as the other conditional statements are on the `INNER JOIN` portions

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment(that I deleted) I now understood what you are saying with Placeholder. Thanks again!

Comment: could you please take a look at the updated code block in the question. I adapted your code to work with Joomla but I do still need help to get it working. Thank you very much!