# Removing empty spaces and BR from string in echo

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got the below code but at the moment it generates a string of results but with about 40+ empty spaces.

```
$user_  = JFactory::getUser();
$db     = JFactory::getDBO();
$levels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($user->id);
foreach($levels as $key => $level)
{
  $query  = 'SELECT title FROM #__pf_projects';
  $query .= ' WHERE access = ' . $level . " AND TRIM(title) != ''";
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $projectlist = $db->loadResult($query).'<br>';
  echo $projectlist;
}
```

At first I thought that `array_filter()` would be good here but as PatrickQ points out it is a string so the array filter won't work. 
Then I adapted the code according to the answer from Don't Panic. This adapted code is what you can see above.

It returns now a list like this.

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
http://www.domain1.com
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
http://www.domain5.com
http://www.domain23.com
http://www.domain65.com
http://www.domain213.com
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

So how to adapt the code to just get a list like this:

```
http://www.domain1.com
http://www.domain5.com
http://www.domain23.com
http://www.domain65.com
http://www.domain213.com
```

When you change the `<br>` into a `,` then the list becomes `,,,,,,,,,,,http,,,,,,httphttphttphttp,,,,,,,` <= I wrote it down a bit shorter.

Comment: What is returned from `$db->loadResult($query);`?

Comment: @PatrickQ It returns a list of titles like: `CM (Lease) (en-GB)http://www.ls.velthovenbv.nlhttp://www.ls.bouwmanbv.nl` but if I would make the echo have `<br>` then it shows about 40+ blanks between those titles.

Comment: If it is returning a string, then that's why `array_filter()` isn't doing anything, it expects an array, not a string.

Comment: Oh that is making perfect sense. Is it still possible with a string though without the array_filter?

Comment: Probably best handled along the lines of Don't Panic's answer, by filtering the result in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's answers I finally figured out a way to get the results. My way is not necessarily the right way for everyone. And someone with more knowledge then me in this area would probably do it different.

Essentially my answer is outputting the entire string with each result inside a div. This will create a lot of empty divs but those are not generated by HTML. They do however show up in the Inspector.

The final code that I use in my script.

```
$user_  = JFactory::getUser();
$db     = JFactory::getDBO();
$levels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($user->id);
foreach($levels as $key => $level)
{
  $query  = 'SELECT title FROM #__pf_projects';
  $query .= ' WHERE access = ' . $level;
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $projectlist = '<div class="project">'.$db->loadResult($query).'</div>';
  echo $projectlist;
}
```

This is now giving me a list like this:

```
http://www.domain1.com
http://www.domain5.com
http://www.domain23.com
http://www.domain65.com
http://www.domain213.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If `array_filter` isn't filtering out empty values, then they probably aren't really empty. Assuming there is some sort of whitespace there rather than nulls or empty strings, you can probably modify your query to trim the title and only return results where there's still something there.

```
SELECT title FROM #__pf_projects
WHERE access = ? AND title IS NOT NULL AND TRIM (title) != ''
```

Or, in terms of your original PHP code:

```
$query  = 'SELECT title FROM #__pf_projects';
$query .= ' WHERE access = ' . $level . " AND TITLE IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(title) != ''";
```

It is best to avoid concatenating variables into your SQL like this, though. If the framework you're using has some way to utilize prepared statements, you should go that route instead.

---

If this still doesn't work, I don't really know what else to try with the query, but you should be able to just check for an empty result in PHP and only echo if there's something to show.

```
$projectlist = $db->loadResult($query);
if (trim($projectlist)) echo $projectlist.'<br>';
```

Comment: I am going to try this out. Thank you for helping as you probably am aware already I am not that good at this. So getting a example really helps me out a lot! So thanks for that!

Comment: @purple11111 after looking at your question again, I'm actually not so sure about this. I didn't notice at first that you were echoing the result inside the foreach. It might still work, but I don't know.

Comment: I am getting a error but that is probably the way I wrote it down. It has to be very specific for Joomla. I wrote it like this:
`  $query .= ' WHERE access = AND title TRIM (title) !=' . $level;` which is wrong. How would you write it down?

Comment: I am updating my question with the code as of now and I made a complete hash of it. With the string and I also forgot to put in the `<br>`. I hope you could take a look at it in about 5 minutes.

Comment: I updated the entire question. I hope it is now way more clearer and bye the way thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: @purple11111 Since you're still getting empty results when checking for `TRIM(title) != ''`, I think title may actually be null. I still think modifying the query is the way to fix this. I added a check for null; give that a try?

Comment: Sorry to report I get the same result. I am going to try preg_split_no_empty

Comment: Sorry, I'm running out of ideas. I added one more option to the answer, but if that doesn't work I think I'm stumped.

Comment: I do not think you are stupid and I am really glad you are helping me out. The latest suggestion you gave did not work. Same goes for the preg split I mentioned that did not work as well. But then I thought. Wait... I write down `<br>` so why not remove this `<br>` and replace it with a div. As HTML does not render empty divs they don't show up on screen either. Fair to say but they do show up in the inspector but that ain't a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, array_filter, if no callback was passed, will remove only falsy elements. String with empty spaces is evaluated to true and therefore will not be remove from array. You can do something like:

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($projectList, function($val) {
    return trim($val);
});

print_r($filteredArray);
```

Also, you can't echo an array. You can use print_r or var_dump.